# Ordenar lista de Strings alfanumérica en java

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Tengo este método, que me devuelve la siguiente salida

- ASR1
- ASR116
- ASR12
- ASR219
- ASR22
- ASR28
- ASR45
- MK11
- MK22

Y la salida que espero es la siguiente

- ASR1
- ASR12
- ASR22
- ASR28
- ASR45
- ASR116
- ASR219
- MK11
- MK22

Mi código es el siguiente:

```html
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("ASR1");
        strings.add("ASR12");
        strings.add("ASR116");
        strings.add("ASR28");
        strings.add("MK11");
        strings.add("ASR45");
        strings.add("ASR219");
        strings.add("ASR22");
        strings.add("MK22");
        /*final List<String> cad = strings.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(code -> Integer.parseInt(code.replaceAll("\\D+",""))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Codes = " + cad);*/

         Collections.sort(strings);
        for (String numero: strings) {
            System.out.println(numero);
        }

    }
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? debo usar stream

Comment: De hecho la lista esta ordenada pues en string `ASR116` es "menor" a `ASR12`, y asi sucesivamente. Ahora bien lo que talvez buscas es la reimplementacion(`overwrite`) del metodo `sort`

Comment: lo que busco es que las ordene de la siguiente manera
ASR1
ASR12
ASR22
ASR28
ASR45
ASR116
ASR219
MK11
MK22

Comment: Eso te digo busca como implementar el `@overwrite` del metodo `sort` e implementalo

Comment: me sirvió este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928524/how-do-i-sort-string-numbers, gracias a todos

Comment: no olvides marcar tu respuesta como correcta, por si alguien mas tiene una duda similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

                String o1StringPart = o1.replaceAll("\\d", "");
                String o2StringPart = o2.replaceAll("\\d", "");


                if(o1StringPart.equalsIgnoreCase(o2StringPart))
                {
                    return extractInt(o1) - extractInt(o2);
                }
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }


            int extractInt(String s) {
                String num = s.replaceAll("\\D", "");
                return num.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(num);
            }

        });
        strings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Esto funciono para mi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928524/how-do-i-sort-string-numbers

Answer (score -1):

Puedes crearte un método que te devuelva un comparador de String. Esta solución la puedes aplicar para cualquier tipo de clase y utilizarla dentro de los Streams.

A continuación te dejo como podrias tener el codigo pero falta por implementar el comparador. Desconozco todas las posibilidades de tu ordenacion por lo que ahi podras aplicarlo a tu gusto.

Por ultimo, te recomiendo este enlace [Sorting in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sorting)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            strings.add("ASR1");
            strings.add("ASR12");
            strings.add("ASR116");
            strings.add("ASR28");
            strings.add("MK11");
            strings.add("ASR45");
            strings.add("ASR219");
            strings.add("ASR22");
            strings.add("MK22");
    
            final List<String> cad = strings
                    .stream()
                    .sorted(compareAlphanumericStrings())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println("Codes = " + cad);
    
            for (String numero : strings) {
                System.out.println(numero);
            }
    
        }
    
        private static Comparator<String> compareAlphanumericStrings() {
            return new Comparator<String>() {
                public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
                    // Aplicar la logica que quieras seguir para ordenar.
                    // Se debe retornar un valor menor de 0, 0 o mayor de 0 dependiendo de si
                    // el primer string deberia ir delante, son iguales o el segundo deberia ir
                    // delante.
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: Pero si ese es prácticamente el mismo código que sale en la pregunta original. Si justamente lo que busca es el comparador. Esto no responde a la pregunta.

Comment: Entonces esta buscando la respuesta hecha en lugar de las herramientas para solucionarlo.

Comment: Las herramientas ya las tiene y parece conocerlas, aparecen ahí en su código. No da con la tecla para implementar el comparador.